# React SSR express,webpack,babel babel doesn't like the CSS in my components

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I have been trying to learn how to SSR with React(without using Next.js) I've gotten to the point that I'm seeing the HTML rendered on the page but once I add the css imports to style the component babel start throwing errors (
C:\Users\Frozen\Desktop\ssr stuff\ssr4\src\App.css:1
body {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
)

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3010,
    static: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', "@babel/preset-react"]
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './public/index.html',
    publicPath: "/"
  })
]

};
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import App from './src/App.js';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('in /');
  fs.readFile(
    path.resolve('./build/index.html'),
    'utf8',
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      }
      const html = data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>`
      )
      console.log(html)
      return res.send(html);
    }
  );
});
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'build')));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server listening on port 3000')
})
```

I also fail to understand why do I have to put the app.use(static) below the app.get('/') aren't middlewares supposed to go one after another in order top to bottom (if I move the app.use(static) above the app.get('/') where I return the  component I don't see the console.log('in /');

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from "./App";

const appElement = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.hydrate(<App/>, appElement)
```

I run
npx webpack
npx babel-node server.js
And I get the css error (if I remove the css import I don't get it but I don't have css in the component)
Also is there a way to rebuild and run server.js once I change something ( like when you use create-react-app ) Also any other suggestions on what I can improve in the current setup will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Install [babel-plugin-css-modules-transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-css-modules-transform)
 `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-css-modules-transform`.
Then include it in .babelrc 
`"plugins": ["css-modules-transform"]`